# Bootstrap popover does not work on first mouseenter event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, jquery-hover

I use the code as follows

```
<a class="reply"  data-content="this is the mail" 
data-original-title="this is the title" rel="popover">this</a>
```

and I triggered the jquery event as follows

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".reply",function(event){
   $(this).popover({placement:'bottom'});
});
```

But the problem is on the first hover event the popover not get showed

from the second event popover get showed normally... What is the reason for this kind of activity and how to rectify it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer adding the following code made it work

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".reply",function(event){
  $(this).popover({placement:'bottom'});
  $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

Comment: -1 The code to initialize a popover should only ever be called once.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `trigger: 'hover'` or `trigger: 'manual'` to the options for the popover.. personally, I would replace your javascript with the following..

```
$(function(){
  $('.reply').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'hover'
  })
})
```

edit, if you have to use the javascript you have set, try this one

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".reply",function(event){
  $(this).popover({
    placement:'bottom', 
    trigger: 'hover'
  }).popover('show');
});
```

Comment: The code of link shown above is created from javascript so there is a  need of delegating the element so the code mentioned by you is not working for me

Comment: alright, not sure what you mean by its created from javascript, but I updated the post to show an example to keep it the way you had it..

Comment: +1 to your comment your comment helped me to find the answer.I posted the answer below. As per your code the popover get displayed and never get hided.

Comment: thats why the `trigger: 'hover'` was added to the options, so its shown on mouse enter, and hides on mouse leave.. and if you could +1 the answer, instead of the comment it would be better..

Comment: The additional code would call popover initialization code on ever `mouseenter` event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `selector` property to delegate the Popover plugin ([see docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)).  Like thus:

```
$('body').popover({
  placement: 'bottom',
  trigger: 'hover',
  selector: '.reply'
});
```

<sub>**Note:** In practice, a more narrow delegate than `'body'` would be recommended.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Just select your element, then call popover with hover

```
$("[rel=popover]").popover({trigger:"hover"});
```